# string formatting in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have the following code that runs in a shell script

```
foo=`seq 1 1 100`
for i in $foo; do
  echo "input$i\_now"
done
```

Here's my question:  Under some conditions, the output prints `input1_now` whereas othertimes it prints `input1\_now`.  I'm sure something is different, but I can't figure out what makes it print one way or the other.  If my code is

```
for i in $foo; do
   echo "input$i_now"
done
```

I will always get `input` with the rest of the line being omitted.

I know I can use `input${i}_now` instead and have it print correctly every time, but I'm mostly interested in understanding why the output is different under seemingly the same conditions.

UPDATE:

In the following example, the first part correctly formats the variables and text such that the `\_` is replaced as `_`.  However, the last part required me to place variables in curly brackets in order to have them formatted correctly.

```
echo "Enter Simulation #: "
read sim

g.mapset results

for i in `seq 1 1 100`; do

file=sim$sim\_run$i\_sum
g.copy $file\@expSim$sim\_$i,$file

file=sim$sim\_run$i\_average
g.copy $file\@expSim$sim\_$i,$file

for year in `seq 2004 1 2006`; do   

    file=sim$sim\_$year\_run$i\_sum
    g.copy $file\@expSim$sim\_$i,$file

    file=sim$sim\_$year\_run$i\_average
    g.copy $file\@expSim$sim\_$i,$file

done

years="2004 2005 2006"
times=`seq -w 1 16 365`
runs=`seq 1 1 100`

for year in $years; do
for ptime in $times; do
    for i in $runs; do
        if [ $i -eq 1 ]; then
            g.copy  vect=sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime}_run${i}@expSim${sim}_${i},sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime}
        fi
        if [ $i -gt  1 ]; then  
        v.patch input=sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime}_run${i}@expSim${sim}_${i} output=sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime} -e -a --o
        fi
    done
done
done
```

Comment: It prints `inputx\_now` consistently for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is `_` supposed to be a placeholder that is sometimes a different character?

In `bash`, `"input$i\_now"` with an actual `_` will always produce `input1\_now`.  Inside double-quotes, `bash` only removes a `\` when it is followed by a `$`, a `` ` ``, a `"`, a `\`, or a newline.  See [“Double Quotes” in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html).  This is the POSIX standard behavior; see [“Double-Quotes” in *Shell Command Language*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_03).

#### UPDATE

If you write `"input$i_now"`, `bash` will just print `input`.  It will not print `input1` or `input1_now`.  It does this because `_` is a valid parameter name character, so `bash` thinks you are asking for the value of the `i_now` parameter.  Unless you have set `i_now` to a non-empty string, `bash` will expand `$i_now` to the empty string, thus turning `"input$i_now"` into `input`.

#### UPDATE 2

Now that you have posted real code, we can see what's going on.

First of all, in the real code you posted, **you never used double-quotes around a parameter expansion.  This makes a difference.**

Outside of double-quotes, a `\` is always removed.  See [“Quote Removal” in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal).   Hence `input$i\_now` (with **no** surrounding double-quotes) expands to `input1_now`.

However, as I explained in my first update, `_` is a parameter name character.  See [“Name” in *Shell Command Language*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_230).  So when `bash` sees `input$i_now`, it takes `i_now` as the parameter name.

Whether or not you're using double-quotes, you **must** separate the parameter name from the following character, if `bash` would otherwise treat the following character as part of the parameter name.  You can do this by putting `\` after the parameter name, or you can do it by putting the parameter name in `{...}`.

It is safer to always use `{...}`, because (as you have discovered?) `\` is handled differently depending on whether it's inside double-quotes.  If you go back and add double-quotes later, and you have used `\`, you will need to change the `\` to `{...}` anyway.

#### UPDATE 3

Here is a demonstration of the effects of `\`, `{...}`, and double-quoting.  First, we set up some variables:

```
$ year=2004 ptime=1 i=1 sim=123
```

Here's what happens with no quoting whatsoever:

```
$ echo vect=sim$sim_pts_$year_$ptime_run$i@expSim$sim_$i,sim$sim_pts_$year_$ptime
vect=sim1@expSim1,sim1
```

Here's what happens if we just use `{...}` without double-quotes:

```
$ echo vect=sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime}_run${i}@expSim${sim}_${i},sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime}
vect=sim123_pts_2004_1_run1@expSim123_1,sim123_pts_2004_1
```

If we add double-quotes, they have no effect:

```
$ echo "vect=sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime}_run${i}@expSim${sim}_${i},sim${sim}_pts_${year}_${ptime}"
vect=sim123_pts_2004_1_run1@expSim123_1,sim123_pts_2004_1
```

Here's what happens if we just use `\`:

```
$ echo vect=sim$sim\_pts\_$year\_$ptime\_run$i@expSim$sim\_$i,sim$sim\_pts\_$year\_$ptime
vect=sim123_pts_2004_1_run1@expSim123_1,sim123_pts_2004_1
```

Notice that each `\` was removed.  The shell removes a `\` if it's not quoted.

If we add double-quotes, they prevent the shell from removing each `\`:

```
$ echo "vect=sim$sim\_pts\_$year\_$ptime\_run$i@expSim$sim\_$i,sim$sim\_pts\_$year\_$ptime"
vect=sim123\_pts\_2004\_1\_run1@expSim123\_1,sim123\_pts\_2004\_1
```

Comment: However, it is not always removing the `_` when preceeded by `$i` in the case of `input$i_now`

Comment: Then you need to edit your post to include a runnable example that outputs `input1_now` instead of `input1\_now`.  Right now your question is basically “My computer acts funny sometimes.  Why?  I can't provide any more details.”

Comment: If I write `input$i_now` it will output `input1` and omit the rest of the line.

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  it doesn't print `input1` rather just `input`.  But I'm still failing to understand why `input$i\_now` prints `input1_now` sometimes and other times `input1\_now`.  It seems inconsistent.  I'm sure I'm doing something different, but I can't see it.

Comment: @konsolebox nope.  I'm editing my question to add the actual code

Comment: THANK YOU!  You have solved my confusion. You are now my code GOD!

Answer (score 6):

Underscore is a valid character in bash variable names so you need to protect the variable name from surrounding characters.

```
foo=`seq 1 1 100`
for i in $foo; do
  echo "input${i}_now"
done
```

The difference:

```
input$i_now    # "input" + $i_now
input${i}_now  # "input" + $i + "_now"
input"$i"_now  # input + "$i" + now
input$i\_now   # input + $1 + _now - \_ "escapes" the underscore
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html

> **name** A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and **beginning with an alphabetic character** *or an underscore*. Also referred to as an identifier.

You have to **protect** the parameter name, either by `PREFIX${braces}SUFFIX`, with `PREFIX"$quotes"SUFFIX` or by escaping - `\` - characters which are valid in parameter names. All "work" but I prefer braces which is also what the documentation refers to:

> The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name.

Comment: that's why I needed to use `input$i\_now`